# Delete an application from iOS device using Push Notification

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

Is there a way could i delete my application from some users iPhone by sending a push notification?. The reason can be a security concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done for any iOS device, but it can be done for devices enrolled in [Mobile Device Management](http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/integration/mdm/) (MDM). Apple has [documented](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_MDM.pdf) all of the available operations, including removing applications remotely.

> An MDM server can manage third-party apps from the App Store, as well as enterprise in-house applications. The server can remove managed apps and their associated
>   data on demand or specify whether the apps are removed when the MDM profile is removed.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't execute any code in response to a push notification, unless your app is already running in the foreground. And you definitely can't programmatically delete your app in any situation.

Your best bet would be to have your app phone home when it starts, and not function unless it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You cant delete your application programmaticaly. But you can block some functionalities using client server communication. For example, Write in your code to send a request if security risks identified, and based on response you can control the program flow.